# File not being created. How can I see the logs of my cron job on my mac?

Tags: bash, macos, cron

I have a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

today=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
yesterday=$(date -v-1d +%F)
tags="comma,separated,values"

cmd="usr/bin/python3 /Users/zs/dev/my-script/my_script.py"

$cmd "--tags" $tags "--dates" $yesterday","$today

open ~/dev/my-script/
```

I have this cron job running every 5 minutes, so I should see a new file in `~/dev/my-script` frequently.

When I run this bash file manually from the terminal, everything works fine and I see the file, the window is opened. But when I run it via the crontab file, the Finder window opens without a new csv file being created.

```
crontab -l
5 * * * * bash ~/dev/my-script/run.sh
# eof
```

Any idea why this file isn't being created?

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing the tilde with the full path to your login directory.

Comment: Thanks, replaced `~` with `/Users/zs/dev/my-script`

Comment: Nope, didn't work...

Comment: Try running `which python3` in Terminal to find its full path, then use that in your script.

Comment: result is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`

Comment: It would be awesome if someone could leave a comment with an example solution. Thanks!

Comment: Just replace `python3` in your script with the full path you just gave.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've updated my original post with the latest changes

Comment: Try adding `DISPLAY=:0` somewhere near the top of your crontab file.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I run `echo $path`, I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin`

Comment: in **macOS**, the `PATH` in **Terminal** is not the same that is passed to a _shell script_ in a _cronjob_, it's `/usr/bin:/bin`. So use _fully qualified pathnames_ or add a `PATH` statement to your _scripts_ run in a _cronjob_. See [PATH (variable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) & [Fully qualified name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name)

Comment: @user3439894 I've updated my original script with the `PATH` statement but still isn't working

Comment: A script that fetches data at a few urls and creates a csv file. The script has been working for weeks so I'm not worried about that piece. It seems to be something in my shell script

Comment: No I don't, should I? If so, how? Also, updated the OP with script changes using /usr/bin/python3

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. So, given the updated original post, any idea what could be wrong here? Thanks

Comment: In **Terminal** if you use the `mail` _command_ is the any mail from `crontab`?  I don't have `python3` and obviously your `my_script.py`, so I cannot test here on my system. That said, your current _shell script_ will create files in `$HOME` not `~/dev/my-script/` unless within `my-script` it is telling it to create the output to `~/dev/my-script/`. Otherwise, I see nothing obvious for it not to work. Sorry I could not have been of more help.

Comment: Wait, `cmd="usr/bin/python3` is missing `/`, it should be `cmd="/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Ah, that was it! It was working before it was just outputting to a different file. Thanks!